# Win CE 6.0 Draw / Show transparent Image / PNG

Tags: visual-c++, embedded, png, windows-ce, transparent

This question is asked often, i tried many of the answers, but did not got it to work..

So here again:

I just wants to display PNGs with transparency on an Windows CE 6.0 Device (ARM4, PicoCOM)

Alphablend is not support on the OS.

Drawing the PNG with IImagingFactory draws the transparency black..

I used the following code snippet:

```
void DrawPng (CWnd *window)
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, 0);

    IImagingFactory* pImageFactory;
    IImage *pImage = NULL;
    CDC *dc = window->GetDC();

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ImagingFactory, NULL,
                                  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                  __uuidof(IImagingFactory),
                                  (LPVOID *)&pImageFactory);

    // Load image from file
    pImageFactory->CreateImageFromFile(_T("\\FFSDisk\\test.png"), &pImage);

    // Get image information
    ImageInfo info;
    pImage->GetImageInfo(&info);

    RECT rc={0,0,info.Width, info.Height};

    // draw jpg/gif etc onto temp dc
    pImage->Draw(dc->GetSafeHdc(), &rc, NULL);

    // Clean up
    pImage->Release();
    pImageFactory->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

I could use the TransparentImage function ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453779.aspx ) but there i can only take 1 color as "transparent" ..

It must be possible, cause when i move the desktop icons over different colors it is always transparent !

Any one knows how to do it?

Thank you.